# SailsJS: Server doesn't seem to be starting on local dev instance

Tags: sails.js

When I start my server with "sails lift" I see these errors:

```
error: Server doesn't seem to be starting.
error: Perhaps something else is already running on port 1337?
```

Even if I try to run from a fresh start or try running with a different port, I get the same errors.  To be clear: the following generates same errors with any port:

```
sails lift --port 2222
```

Creating a brand new sails app from scratch works fine.  Same code seems to work fine on a colleague's machine, but I've tried to setup twice with no luck.

How do I debug this?

Note: I'm not sure that this is actually causing a problem.  I've isolated other errors in my app to other causes and now the server runs despite this output.

I can create a situation with my toy apps where I start Sails with the port in use and then I get a warning in addition to the errors above:

```
warn: error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

My question is about a situation when I get NO ADDITIONAL error or warning. When I DO NOT see EADDRINUSE, but still get error that server doesn't seem to be starting. Is the error the "Server doesn't seem to be starting" coming from Node, Express, Sails?  New to this stack and  interested to know how to isolate the issue.

Comment: Which version of sails are you using?

Comment: the project is 0.9.8 -- though I've also tried it with 0.9.16 with no change

Comment: Have you tried running it on a different port? I know this doesn't answer why it's failing for 1337, but might isolate the issue a little more.

Comment: @Ultrasaurus as sethetter and Eugene have pointed out something else is running on 1337.  I've sometimes had an issue with incorrectly shutting down sails which leaves a process open that I had to manually kill, however, that doesn't explain why you can create a new sails project which will lift.  How do you normally close a sails server?

Comment: As I said before, and just clarified above, it happens on any port I've tried.  It also doesn't actually prevent the server from running (mentioned in my note), so it is likely a spurious error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeing the "Server doesn't seem to be starting" message, but are still able to access the server, then the issue is just that the server took longer to start than expected.  The `liftTimeout` config can help with this.  In your **config/local.js** file, set:

```
liftTimeout: 1000 // defaults to 500
```

and the problem should go away, assuming your server takes less than a second to start.  Adjust the timeout according to your needs.

Comment: sounds like it would work, but it seems to have no effect, even increasing to 10000 -- I assume those are milliseconds?  Doesn't seem to wait 10s before reporting the error. Do I need a particular version of sails for this?  (It wasn't in my config/local.js, but I added it)

Comment: Yes, this was only added in v0.10 (which is in beta), specifically v0.10.0-rc5.  The problem existed before that obviously, but unfortunately the timeout value was hardcoded to 500.  If it's really annoying you you can search the Sails code for `Perhaps something else is already running` and edit the hard-coded value.  And yes, it's milliseconds.

Comment: awesome.  I will look forward to upgrading to 0.10 :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in some another appliation which listening this port.

You can fix that in few ways.

1. Configure at `config/local.js` port where Sails will start, i.e.

   ```
   module.exports = {
       port: 3000
   }
   ```
2. See what applications listening port 1337. It can be i.e. nginx which listening 1337 port. When you will find application, reconfigure it with other options or kill it.
3. If you are using nginx for proxying requests to NodeJS, you can't use the same port for nginx and Sails. So, for example, you have nginx listening 80 port which redirects requests from 80 port to 3000. Then you must configure Sails to run on 3000 port and set in `config/local.js` also proxyHost and proxyPort parameters like this.

   ```
   module.exports = {
       port: 3000,
       environment: 'production',
       proxyHost: 'yourhost.com',
       proxyPort: 80
   }
   ```

Comment: see my elaboration above.  this is not the issues of something running on the port I'm trying to use (though thanks for the nice explanation of port configuration!)

Comment: Which version of Sails are you using? Also could happened that node starts app.js twice. When you lift your application type ```ps -aux | grep node``` and see what it will print.